# IntelliJ IDEAでファイルをダブルクリックをしても開けなくなった場合の対処法

Tags: intellij-idea

## 事象

IntelliJ IDEAでmdファイルの紐づけが外れたらしく、「?」マークが表示され、
ダブルクリックをしてもエディタが表示されなくなってしまった
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 行ったこと

- Invalidate Cachesですべて選択し、再起動
- IntelliJを終了し、.ideaディレクトリを削除後、IntelliJを起動

上記を行っても改善されませんでした

## 環境

- IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)

  - Build #IU-232.9921.47, built on September 13, 2023
- Windows 10

---

解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、
ご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

## 追記

> ここに書かれている手順で設定更新できないでしょうか。

こちら、「associate with File Type」を選択しても何も表示されませんでした……
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: [ここ](https://pleiades.io/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#configure-associations-between-filename-patterns-and-file-types)に書かれている手順で設定更新できないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちら、何もウインドウが表示されず、関連付けができませんでした……

Answer (score 0, accepted):

何故か、「composer install」という文字列を入れるとIntelliJがmdを認識しなくなるという現象でした……

一旦composer installという文字列をMarkdownから抜くと認識しましたので、
なんかしらのバグなのかとおもいます……